# Solution for channel bonding between Windows 7 and Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, bonding

I've been looking for a solution for channel bonding between a Windows 7 system and a Linux system. Linux seems to have the capability to bond regardless of underlying hardware. Windows seems to be generally limited to NICs whose manufactures provide drivers specifically for their hardware. Looking at the Windows DDK docs, it seems like it should be possible to create a driver that presents its own NIC and simply splits the packets between a set of configured NICs regardless of underlying hardware. I understand that what ever method is used, in order to be used, there needs to be cooperation between both ends of the connection. So such a driver for Windows would need an equivalent, matching item for Linux. Theoretically, I could learn the Windows DDK and Linux drivers and write my own, but I'd really prefer not to go through all of that.

Is there such a driver that already exists for Windows 7 that is also compatible in some way with Linux?

For reference: Linux with one on-board GbE NIC and one add-in GbE NIC directly connected to Windows 7 with same arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

You need a switch in between, and an EtherChannel configured on the switch for the ports coming from each system.

Any link aggregation driver on Windows should just present a single virtual Layer 1 device to the switch, just like the Linux bonding driver does.

You cannot do link aggregation over crossover, not without writing your own driver anyway.

Comment: Intel's teaming drivers include an option for adaptive load balancing (ALB). Their description reads, "This team type works with any switch or hub." I suspect this means it can work through crossover.

Comment: When I said "writing your own driver" it looks like Intel have done that for you and called it "Advanced Network Services Teaming".